# excel vba - adding columns in table based on list

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

I'm trying to insert columns into a table ("TableTotal") based on a list of locations Starting at B3 and going down. That list will varie in size depending on how many location there is.

I create sheets, insert tables, and rename the tables using

```
Sub RunAllMacros()
CreateSheetsFromAList
CopyTable
CreateSheetsFromAList2
End Sub
 Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("B3")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell

End Sub

Sub CopyTable()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Dim Source As Range

Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("TableTemp[#All]")

' Begin the loop.
For i = 3 To WS_Count

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Select ' just select the sheet
    Source.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name = "Table" & ActiveSheet.Name

Next i

End Sub
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList2()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("M1")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

The last 2 sheets created with "CreateSheetsFromAList2" need to have tables for doing a "TOTAL" calculation based on each of the initial tables created.

I have a template table that I want to copy and paste in those sheets but I need to insert first columns that are dependent on the first list used from the Range "B3".

I have managed through a CountA to get the number of columns to be inserted and put them in the right place in my "TableTotal" using the below

```
Sub Insert_Columns()
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("M").Resize(, Range("C3").Value).Insert
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

This properly insert the right number of columns but they have headers as Column 1 thru X based on how many locations I have

I'm looking for a way to insert those columns with the specific headers name based on the B3 list directly.

Additionally each of those table columns will contain a formula that will reference the tables created in CreateSheetsFromAList using the same TableName reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sub:

```
Sub insertColumnsWithHeaders(headers As Range)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = headers.End(xlDown).row To headers.End(xlUp).row Step -1
        columns("M").Insert
        Range("N1") = Cells(i, headers.Cells(1, 1).Column)
    Next

End Sub
```

Headers needs to be at most 1 column wide. Inserts columns after column M with headers specified in the range passed as argument.